# Using the command-line install anaconda on Mac

Tags: python, command-line, anaconda, apple-m1

I am following anaconda docs to install via command-line
[doc link](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/#using-the-command-line-install)

when I try to use below command,

```
shasum -a 256 /path/filename
```

it shows

```
shasum: /Users/sky/anaconda: Is a directory
```

as below screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the path to the file that you downloaded - because you want to check the file, but you're giving the path to a directory

As an example, I downloaded the installer to Downloads so I would check it like so (replace 'USERNAME' with your username):

```
shasum -a 256 /Users/USERNAME/Downloads/Anaconda3-2022.05-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg
```

But you don't really have to do that to proceed with the installation